# ionic facebook login - not waiting for response

Tags: facebook, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple Facebook login issue with ionic. I have tried Async - Await and several other approaches to get it to wait for response. The login works fine but it will not stop for me to work with the response.

How do I add any wait here?? I know this is callback hell.. I just want to grab a few pieces of info. That is all.

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';


 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public fb: Facebook) {


            doFacebookLogin(){
                let env = this;
                this.fb.login(permissions)
                  .then(function(response){

                        env.fb.api("/me?fields=name", params)
                          .then(function(user) {
                            //
                            // do something here with user data
                            //
                          })  // env.fb.api(

                  }, function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                  });  //  this.fb.login(permissions)
              }
```

Thanks
Phil

Comment: what exactly do you need the wait functionality for? It will help me get to a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always use `fat arrow` [**function**](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_arrow-function-syntax) as shown below.Then no callback hell.

```
doFacebookLogin(){
            let env = this;
            this.fb.login(permissions)
              .then((response)=>{

                    env.fb.api("/me?fields=name", params)
                      .then((user)=> {
                          // do something here with user data
                       })  
              }, (error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :)